# Select which OS to boot when dual-booting Windows 7 and Ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, linux, ubuntu, multi-boot

I'd like to dual-boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu. If I install Ubuntu on a new partition on the same HDD as my Windows 7 installation (on a seperate partition) how would I could about choosing which OS I'd like to use on boot?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu will install [GRUB 2](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2), a boot loader that will present you with boot options. You will be able to choose which operating system to boot, either Ubuntu (one of its kernels, or recovery mode), or Windows.

> GRUB 2 is the default boot loader and manager for Ubuntu since version 9.10 (Karmic Koala). As the computer starts, GRUB 2 either presents a menu and awaits user input or automatically transfers control to an operating system kernel

You can [change GRUB's options through Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Configuring_GRUB_2). If you choose to uninstall Ubuntu at one point, you need to reinstall or fix the existing boot loader though, for example with [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/).

Comment: Thanks slhck, you were right. Previously I had Windows 7 and Windows 8 Dev Preview installed. I deleted the Windows 8 Partition to be replaced with Ubuntu, however the Windows 8 boot loader (think I'm right in saying that?) remains. Not a problem, since when I choose that from the GRUB menu it defaults to my Windows 7 installation since there are no longer any choices, but it says "Windows 8" in the GRUB menu.. how could I change that to Windows 7? Not important, but would just be nice for clarity. :)

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, if you installed Ubuntu last, there won't be any Windows boot loader remaining, it'll just boot into Windows. If it really says "Windows 8" instead of "Windows 7", that [seems to be rather complicated to fix](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1287602). Unfortunately, since you didn't ask this specific question before, I can't help you – not a GRUB expert, at least I have no machine to try it with. I'd suggest asking another question, mentioning all possible details and your situation! Cheers

Comment: Not to worry, I'm sure I'll be able to live with an '8' instead of '7'. :) Thanks for your help.